# React-Native onSubmitEditting taking too much time to execute function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am following a react-native tutorial but am having some trouble with React contexts and ActivityIndicator, I dont know where the problem lies, but I will try to be as descriptive as possible.
The problem:-
[image]

The code :
I am using contexts to provide the app with the location that has been searched and then searching for that location within my mock data, later returning the restaurants around that location.

complete source code at https://github.com/diivi/KiloBite/blob/main/src/services/location/location.context.js
Here I am using the  onSearch function and passing it as a context prop to my search box to use with onSubmitEditing.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you call `onSearch` and there you `setILoading(true)`
and `setKeyword(searchKeyword)`.

Then in the `useEffect` you use the `keyword` you set in `onSearch`. Your `useEffect` runs only in `keyword` changes (see dependencies).

Try to add `onSearch` in your dependencies (look below).
Or maybe even `locationRequest, locationTransform`.
I would also try `setIsLoading` and generally try to put as dependencies everything you use in your `useEffect`.

```js
const onSearch = (searchKeyword) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setKeyword(searchKeyword);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!keyword.length) {
      return;
    }

    locationRequest(keyword.toLowerCase())
      .then(locationTransform)
      .then((result) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setLocation(result);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError(err);
      });
  }, [keyword, onSearch]);
```

BUT, at the end I wonder, why you use a `useEffect`?
Why don't you just move all the code in `onSearch`:

```js
const onSearch = (searchKeyword) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    // setKeyword(searchKeyword); // not needed
if (!searchKeyword.length) {
      return;
    }
    locationRequest(searchKeyword.toLowerCase())
      .then(locationTransform)
      .then((result) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setLocation(result);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError(err);
      });
  };
```

Comment: moving everything inside onSearch starts an infinite loop for some reason, hence I am trying to use useEffect. Adding all the dependencies you recommended stop anything from loading in the app apparently :/, most of the UI is gone

Comment: Oh sorry for the infinite loop. It's probably because in the above function, I was still checking for `!keyword.length`. Try with `!searchKeyword.length`, since keyword is not used anymore. Further when I say try all the dependencies, what I mean is, try to see which functions or variables change should trigger the `useEffect`.

Comment: It still does not work, the function works perfectly fine and I have followed by code line by line logging everything I am doing, but still getting the long delay between the loading screen and pressing the search button, cant figure out why this is happening

Comment: Maybe it's because you set loading to true in `onSearch`, and then you set it back to false after the `keyword` is updated, which means the component has to rerender. Try setting the  `setIsLoading(true);` in the use `useffect`. After the `if (!keyword.length) { return; }`

Comment: still the same result :( could it be that the issue is device specific? have you tested the code ? I am noticing two things : 1. the navbar moves above the keyboard and then glitches when i enter submit 2. the delay after submit and before loading , both visible in the gif. Maybe I can wait and put the question on bounty tomorrow

Comment: Actually, how do you call the `onSearch`? Do you use an arrow function? Like: `search={() => this.search(searchKeyword)}`. Arrow functions make the component to re-render. Try using `bind`, like: `search={this.search.bind(this, searchKeyword)}`

Comment: BTW I think you do use an arrow function, in your `searchComponent` `onSubmitEditing={() => {search(searchKeyword);}}`. But because you use a functional component, you don't need `this` just try  `onSubmitEditing={search(searchKeyword)}`